How do I drop git commits without using interactive mode?
I want to write a script that deletes certain commits from a long git history but all the guides and answers I've found do it with "git rebase -i" changing "pick" to "drop".
Specifically, I'm writing something to download issues so that you can edit them inside a project's codebase and upload the results, but now want to make the "issues" stuff a separate project instead of cluttering up the other project's git history. All commits relevant to the issues modify files in "issues/" and none modify both issues/* and the main code tree.
What is the scriptable command-line equivalent to drop a commit from the history?

You probably want git filter-repo.
Specifically
git filter-repo --path issues/

to keep only the commits touching issues/*, and
git filter-repo --invert-paths --path issues/

to keep everything else.

Fab. Many thanks. -M
